# Question about saving user current location into database

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to save user current location to firebase that include time and address. Basically, my code is working, but just the first location address always shows "label", not address. Therefore, when I re-run the app, it always has a label data in my firebase realtime database. I don't know how to fix it. I attached my code and the picture of my database below.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if locations.count > 0 {
        let location = locations[locations.count-1]
        let maxAge:TimeInterval = 60;
        let requiredAccuracy:CLLocationAccuracy = 80;
        let locationIsValid:Bool = Date().timeIntervalSince(location.timestamp) < maxAge && location.horizontalAccuracy <= requiredAccuracy;
        if locationIsValid
        {
            NSLog(",,, location : %@",location);
            NSLog("valid locations.....");
        }
    }

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locations[0].coordinate.latitude, longitude: locations[0].coordinate.longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitudeDelta: 0.005))
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!) { (placemarks, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print("Error: " + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        }
        let pm = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]
        if pm.count > 0 {
            let pm = placemarks![0]

            let subThoroughfare = pm.subThoroughfare ?? ""
            let thoroughfare = pm.thoroughfare ?? ""
            let locality = pm.locality ?? ""
            let administrativeArea = pm.administrativeArea ?? ""
            let postalCode = pm.postalCode ?? ""
            let country = pm.country ?? ""
            let address = (subThoroughfare)+" "+(thoroughfare)+" "+(locality)+","+(administrativeArea)+" "+(postalCode)+" "+(country)

            self.myAddress.text = "\(address)"
        }
    }
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm:ss"
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    let timestampFormattedStr = formatter.string(from: (locationManager.location?.timestamp)!)
    let timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: NSTimeZone.local.secondsFromGMT())
    let timeZoneName = timeZone.localizedName(.standard, locale: NSLocale.current)
    let timestampWithTimeZone = "\(timestampFormattedStr) \(String(describing: timeZoneName))"
    let values = ["Time": timestampWithTimeZone,"Address": myAddress.text as Any]

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("userLocations").childByAutoId().setValue(values)
}
```

And below is the picture of my database
[image]

Comment: At first time while **reverseGeocodeLocation** was decoding, you saved address into Firebase.

Comment: Call Firebase line inside reverseGeocodeLocation block, when received address. You problem will be fixed. Let me know, If you need any other help.

Comment: @Surjeet How to do that? Sorry I am new in this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reverseGeocodeLocation` block is asynchronous. This means your Firebase code happens before the block is called. When you assign `self.myAddress` you have already submitted to the database. To fix this put the firebase code inside the block.

```
if pm.count > 0 {
        let pm = placemarks![0]

        let subThoroughfare = pm.subThoroughfare ?? ""
        let thoroughfare = pm.thoroughfare ?? ""
        let locality = pm.locality ?? ""
        let administrativeArea = pm.administrativeArea ?? ""
        let postalCode = pm.postalCode ?? ""
        let country = pm.country ?? ""
        let address = (subThoroughfare)+" "+(thoroughfare)+" "+(locality)+","+(administrativeArea)+" "+(postalCode)+" "+(country)

        self.myAddress.text = "\(address)"
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm:ss"
        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
        let timestampFormattedStr = formatter.string(from: (locationManager.location?.timestamp)!)
        let timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: NSTimeZone.local.secondsFromGMT())
        let timeZoneName = timeZone.localizedName(.standard, locale: NSLocale.current)
        let timestampWithTimeZone = "\(timestampFormattedStr) \(String(describing: timeZoneName))"
        let values = ["Time": timestampWithTimeZone,"Address": myAddress.text as Any]

        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("userLocations").childByAutoId().setValue(values)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this code:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {        
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    if let location = locations.last {
        latitudeLabel.text = "Latitude: " + "\(location.coordinate.latitude)"
        longitudeLabel.text = "Longitude: " + "\(location.coordinate.longitude)"

        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error found while reverse GEO coding.")
                return
            }

            if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                var fullAddress = ""
                if let name = placemark.name {
                    fullAddress.append("Name: " + name)
                }

                if let country = placemark.country {
                    fullAddress.append("\nCountry: " + country)
                }

                if let countryCode = placemark.isoCountryCode {
                    fullAddress.append("\nCountry code: " + countryCode)
                }

                if let locality = placemark.locality {
                    fullAddress.append("\nLocality: " + locality)
                }

                if let postal = placemark.postalCode {
                    fullAddress.append("\nPostal: " + postal)
                }

                if let thoroughfare = placemark.thoroughfare {
                    fullAddress.append("\nThoroughfare: " + thoroughfare)
                }

                if let administrativeArea = placemark.administrativeArea {
                    fullAddress.append("\nAdministrativeArea: " + administrativeArea)
                }

                if let subLocality = placemark.subLocality {
                    fullAddress.append("\nSubLocality: " + subLocality)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**You have to stop update location.**

Hope you got your issue and this code will work for you.